# How to make Ubuntu text color easier to read?

Tags: icons, colors, text

In Ubuntu 14.04 default text and icons color are gray and these are less clear and not easily to read. How can I make that colors darker and change to black or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `gtk-main.css` file in `Ambiance` theme from following path via Terminal:

```bsh
gksudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
```

or in `Radiance` theme like below:

```bsh
gksudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
```

Then edit following lines:

```bsh
@define-color fg_color #4c4c4c;     # identifies icons text color
@define-color text_color #3C3C3C;   # identifies color for text
```

and change both lines value to new value as following:

```bsh
@define-color fg_color #000000;
@define-color text_color #000000;
```

Save the opened file, log off and log in back to see the changes.

---

You can change that lines directly by using `sed` command:

```bsh
sudo sed -i.bak 's:@define-color \(text_color\|fg_color\) #......;:@define-color \1 #000000;:1' /path/to/gtk-main.css
```

Change in screenshots:

Before change:

[image: before change]

Highlighted lines will be change:

[image: in change]

After change:

[image: after change]

Comment: Isn't there an easy GUI way to do this in Unity? In the Settings? Gnome 2 & XFCE, gnome 3 I think, have different icon sets available (and window manager / appearance styles / Themes) that are easy to change

Comment: @Xen2050 I tried to find the same settings in dconf-editor but I didn't find.

Comment: I guess tweaking a theme isn't one-click easy... I'm lazy & would go with a different theme